# How to process APIGatewayProxyRequestEvent event body as a Json

Tags: java, json, string, exception, aws-api-gateway

I have the following code.

This is the correct input which will not throw an error or exception.

```
{
name : "Hello"
age : 24
}
```

```
    public APIGatewayProxyResponseEvent handleRequest(final APIGatewayProxyRequestEvent event, final Context context) {
                 String requestString = event.getBody();
                 JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(requestString);
                 if (!Strings.isNullOrEmpty(jsonObject.getString("name")) {
                    //blah blah
                 } else {
            (!Strings.isNullOrEmpty(jsonObject.getString("fullName")) {
               //blah blah
                   
        }
```

```
{
fullName: "Hello"
age: 24
}
```

If I do not pass the name, but pass fullName I get an error

jsonObject.getString("name") is throwing an exception so my code never reaches the else block. What is the best way to read and process APIGatewayProxyRequestEvent. Both the request body are valid cases.

Thank you.

Comment: Please share your input you passed from client

Comment: Which JSON library are you using?

Comment: import org.json.JSONObject;